# Securing android to odoo connection

Tags: android, security, odoo

I'am a newbie to android development. I'am developing an application which have to connect with odoo via the odoo api. What is the best way to secure data between the app and the server?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: This is a broad topic. So you are interested in the security of the network connection used to pass information back and forth between android device and odoo server? Or are you just looking for information on how to get the data from the server?

Comment: So, do you mind telling me what you looking for?

Comment: Hi, @philipstack thanks for your response. Actually I am interested in the security of the data exchanged between android app and the server. To be more clear,  to get data from the server I use  the odoo api with xmlrpc so I need the users credentials like email, password,  and so on. These information come from the android app and I'd like to encrypt them

Comment: You could use xmlrpcs

Comment: If you are using an ssl certificate and https on your webserver communication should be encrypted. Are you looking for something more secure than this? (Not that I am saying https is the greatest security)

Comment: Consider looking at [OdooJsonRpcClient ](github.com/kasim1011/OdooJsonRpcClient) for Android.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that all data is encrypted between your app and the odoo server, don't connect directly to the python http server.

Instead you should install a proxy (i like using nginx), a ssl certificate and force the use of https protocol in your nginx configuration, and i recommend using this configuration for all connections to the server apart from localhost.

My last advice is: for apps, i prefer using odoo's json-rpc interface, if you didn't know about it take a look!